# Execute jQuery in a bookmark without returning an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code in Javascript:

`document.querySelectorAll("img[src*='SOMETHING']").forEach(function(energy){energy.parentNode.remove()})`

I can add a bookmark with this code prepending it with `javascript:`. When I click the bookmark, the code is executed.

This is above code's equivalent in jQuery:

`$("img[src*='SOMETHING']").parent().remove()`

But if I prepend it with `javascript:` and add it to a bookmark and click it on a page, the source changes to `[object Object]` and if I append the jQuery code with `.val()` I get an empty page.

**How can I modify the jQuery code not to do that after clicking the bookmark?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that because jquery always return an object and the code you use for your bookmarklet doesn't know what to do with the return value, so it displays it. While using vanillajs, the code just executes without returning anything, hence silently for you.

If you wrap your code into a self-executing function which itslef isn't returning anything, it should do the trick:

```
javascript:(function(){/* Whatever you want to do here*/})()
```

Comment: I knew there's a way for jQuery not to return anything but didn't think about this one. It worked, thanks.